# how to create a method which creates new instance from class?

Tags: javascript, class, methods

I have `Bmw` class extended from `Car` class I created before, now I need to create a `createNewBmwCar` method inside `Bmw` `class` which will create new instance from `Bmw` class...

```js
class Bmw extends Car {
  constructor(options) {
    this._model = options.model;
    this._year = options.year;
    this._price = options.price;
  }
  static createNewBmwCar() {
    // return FIXME: let newCar = new Bmw();
  }
}
```

Comment: What's wrong with the code you have commented out?

Comment: Do you see an _“Uncaught `ReferenceError`: must call `super` constructor before using '`this`' in derived class constructor”_ in the console?

Comment: @SebastianSimon - Doh! I looked only at the `static` method they were asking about, glossed right over the constructor. :-D

Comment: I need to return new Bmw instance whenever i call this function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to instantiate `Bmw` in this `static` method:

```js
class Car {};

class Bmw extends Car {
  constructor(options) {
    super(options);
    this._model = options.model;
    this._year = options.year;
    this._price = options.price;
  }
  static createNewBmwCar(options) {
    return new Bmw({
        model: "BMW",
        year: options.year,
        price: options.price
    });
  }
}

let myBMW = Bmw.createNewBmwCar({
    year: 2020,
    price: "1$"
});

console.log(myBMW);
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem isn't the `static` method, it's the constructor. Derived constructors **must** call `super()`, and must do so before they can use `this`.

If you fix that, and add the necessary parameter(s) to `createNewBmwCar`, it works (but keep reading):

```js
class Car { }
class Bmw extends Car {
    constructor(options) {
        super(); // <=========
        this._model = options.model;
        this._year = options.year;
        this._price = options.price;
    }
    static createNewBmwCar(options) {
        let newCar = new Bmw(options);
        return newCar;
    }
}

const beemer = Bmw.createNewBmwCar({
    model: "fancy",
    year: "recent",
    price: "lots",
});
console.log(beemer._model); // "fancy"
```

You do have a second option that may be more flexible: You can use `this` instead of `Bmw` in the `static` method, since it will refer to the constructor you call the static method on:

```
static createNewBmwCar(options) {
    let newCar = new this(options);
    //               ^^^^
    return newCar;
}
```

```js
class Car { }
class Bmw extends Car {
    constructor(options) {
        super(); // <=========
        this._model = options.model;
        this._year = options.year;
        this._price = options.price;
    }
    static createNewBmwCar(options) {
        let newCar = new Bmw(options);
        return newCar;
    }
}

const beemer = Bmw.createNewBmwCar({
    model: "fancy",
    year: "recent",
    price: "lots",
});
console.log(beemer._model); // "fancy"
```

That has the advantage that if you create a subclass of `Bmw`, and then call the `static` method on the subclass, you'll get an instance of the subclass, rather than a `Bmw`:

```js
class Car { }
class Bmw extends Car {
    constructor(options) {
        super(); // <=========
        this._model = options.model;
        this._year = options.year;
        this._price = options.price;
    }
    static createNewBmwCar(options) {
        let newCar = new this(options);
        return newCar;
    }
}
class BmwSpecial extends Bmw { }

const beemer = BmwSpecial.createNewBmwCar({
    model: "fancy",
    year: "recent",
    price: "lots",
});
console.log(beemer instanceof BmwSpecial); // true, would be false with the earlier version
```

Comment: I go into this stuff -- both derived constructors and static methods -- in detail in my recent book *JavaScript: The New Toys* (Chapter 4). Links in my profile if you're interested.